# Is there any way to change the border title of a JScrollPane dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jscrollpane

I am using the *Swing* GUI editor on the *IntelliJ IDEA* IDE. In the properties navigator of the JScrollPane there is a property called "**border**" and, inside of it, a sub-property called "**title**". There I can set a title to the pane, but I cannot find how to change this title dynamically.

I have tried all the reasonable possibilities that would work with most common swing components, like getting the border (as this title is apparently a property of the pane **border**) and finding some `setText()` or `setTitle()` method somewhere, but I could find nothing...

Comment: `JScrollPane` doesn't actually have a "title" property.  From the sounds of if, you've used a `TitledBorder` instead.  You might want to change the `border` property instead, see [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) instead.  You might also want to stop using the UI editors until you get a better understanding of how Swing works, they won't do you any benefits in the long run - IMHO

Comment: Thank you, @MadProgrammer, I am taking the advice. BTW I did not want to go deeper into Swing, since I would do that on JavaFX. I just needed something reasonably fast to solve some concrete problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, and as read in the question comments, the whole thing was going around the **border** property:

```
String borderTitle = "My fancy title";
Border etchedBorder = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
Border etchedTitledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(etchedBorder, borderTitle);

myScrollPane.setBorder(etchedTitledBorder);
```

Note I used the createEtchedBorder(), but any other available border method creator can be used.

There are probably better ways to achieve this, because in that way you need to set a new **border** every time you need to change the title instead of just changing the value of its title parameter, but this is doing the trick pretty well.

I hope this can be useful.